# why am I getting "integer expected" error in the Android manifest?

Tags: android

I think I've asked this before but I can't find the question now, and I don't think I got an answer.

In the android manifest on the first line ""

I'm getting an error marker (with a red X).  When I mouse over the red x it says-

"Manifest attribute 'minSdkVersion' is set to '2.1'. Integer is expected."

does anyone know what could be causing this or how I might fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

minSdkVersion should be 7 for 2.1.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Comment: thank you.  why do you think it automatically generated 1.5, before I set it to 2.1?  will I need to re-write it every time?

thanks again

Comment: Mine doesn't do that, so I suppose the Android plugin might be out of date. Try updating it.